# Loading library.js from bad path

Tags: sapui5, directory-structure

I have updated OpenUI5 of my project from 1.42.7 to 1.60.12 (LTS)

If I try to run the app with the new version, I have this error:

> Uncaught Error: failed to load 'sap/ui/core/library.js' from resources/sap/ui/core/library.js: 404 - Not Found**

[image: error]

The tree structure of my project has OpenUI5 files into `resources/openui` path:

[image: current project folder structure]

In index.html, I set `src` in this mode:

```html
<script id="sap-ui-bootstrap"
  src="resources/openui/sap-ui-core.js"
  data-sap-ui-theme="sap_belize"
  data-sap-ui-xx-bindingSyntax="complex"
  data-sap-ui-libs="sap.m"
  data-sap-ui-preload=""
  data-sap-ui-resourceroots='{
    "ui5bp": "./",
    "model": "./model"
  }'
></script>
```

It seems that the first call of `sap-ui-core.js` finishes correctly (from `Webcontent/resources/openui`) but then the call of `library.js` is called from `Webcontent/resources/`, not from `Webcontent/resources/openui`.

In 1.42 version, all works fine.
Note: if I try to retrieve OpenUI5 resources from CDN, all works fine...

```
src="https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/1.60.12/resources/sap-ui-core.js"
```

Comment: Did the below answer help?

Answer (score 4):

## Option 1 (recommended)

Move the UI5 resources to the `resources` folder directly underneath.

```
˅ resources
  ˃ openui
  ˅ sap
    ˃ base
    ˃ f
    ˃ m
    ...
  ...
  sap-ui-core.js
```

According to the topic *[Bootstrapping: Loading and Initializing - Initialization Process](https://ui5.sap.com/#/topic/91f2c9076f4d1014b6dd926db0e91070.html#loio91f2c9076f4d1014b6dd926db0e91070)*, UI5 will try to fetch library resources from the following path by default:

> Library bootstrap file `/<context-path>/resources/<library-name>/library(-preload).js`

Having a deviating path (`/resources/openui/<library-name>/` in between) makes fetching the library files incompatible with default settings.

## Option 2 (without changing the folder structure)

Define a new default *base URL* in index.html as early as possible. E.g. via the *[global configuration object](https://ui5.sap.com/#/topic/91f08de06f4d1014b6dd926db0e91070.html#loio91f08de06f4d1014b6dd926db0e91070__ul_osf_ttl_wk):*

```html
<script>
  window["sap-ui-config"] = {
    resourceRoots: {
      "": "./resources/openui/", // <-- new base URL
      "ui5bp": "./",
      // ...
    },
    libs: "sap.ui.core, sap.m",
    async: true,
    theme: "sap_belize",
    compatVersion: "edge",
    // ...
  };
</script>
<script id="sap-ui-bootstrap" src="resources/openui/sap-ui-core.js"></script>
```

This one works too as resolving `""` will always work as a fallback

> Note that the empty prefix (`""`) will always match and thus serves as a fallback for any search. <sup>[source](https://openui5nightly.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/jQuery.sap/methods/jQuery.sap.registerModulePath)</sup>